# Enable message compression for WebSockets in Go

Tags: go, websocket, server, client

I have simple client - server websocket communication and I want to know if it's possible to enable message compression for the websockets. I am using Golang library `gorila/websocket`.

And there are configurations like `EnableCompression bool` or `EnableWriteCompression(bool) method`, but it does not working as expected or maybe I cannot figure out how to use it.

`Expected behaviour:`

I am expecting to send for example - 50kb message and to be compressed to 10-20kb or something like this. But it seems that `EnableWriteCompression` is not working as expected or I am not using it in the right way.

The code:

`server.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

func socketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    conn.EnableWriteCompression(true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error during upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    n := 0
    for n <= 10 {
        messageType, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error during message reading:", err)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("Received: %s", message)
        err = conn.WriteMessage(messageType, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error during message writing:", err)
            break
        }
        n++
    }
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Index Page")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/socket", socketHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}
```

`client.go`:

```
// client.go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var done chan interface{}
var interrupt chan os.Signal

func receiveHandler(connection *websocket.Conn) {
    defer close(done)
    for {
        _, msg, err := connection.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error in receive:", err)
            return
        }
        log.Printf("Received: %s\n", msg)
    }
}

func main() {
    done = make(chan interface{})    // Channel to indicate that the receiverHandler is done
    interrupt = make(chan os.Signal) // Channel to listen for interrupt signal to terminate gracefully

    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt) // Notify the interrupt channel for SIGINT

    socketUrl := "ws://localhost:8080" + "/socket"
    conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(socketUrl, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting to Websocket Server:", err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()
    go receiveHandler(conn)

    // Our main loop for the client
    // We send our relevant packets here
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(1) * time.Millisecond * 1000):
            conn.EnableWriteCompression(true)
            conn.SetCompressionLevel(1)
            err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Some message to send!"))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Error during writing to websocket:", err)
                return
            }

        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("Received SIGINT interrupt signal. Closing all pending connections")

            err := conn.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }

            select {
            case <-done:
                log.Println("Exiting....")
            case <-time.After(time.Duration(1) * time.Second):
                log.Println("Exiting....")
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you did post some code, but you didn't indicate what you expect, and what doesn't work as you expect. Can you give more details ?

Comment: Thanks, I made a "expected behaviour" section.

Answer (score 4):

As per documentation:

> EnableWriteCompression enables and disables write compression of
> subsequent text and binary messages. **This function is a noop if compression was not negotiated with the peer.**

You need to setup the compression on `Updater` and `Dialer` level, so that it can be negotiated during the connection upgrade:

```golang
// for server
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    EnableCompression: true,
}

// for client
dialer := websocket.Dialer{
    Proxy:             http.ProxyFromEnvironment, // From default dialer
    HandshakeTimeout:  45 * time.Second, // From default dialer
    EnableCompression: true,
}
...
conn, _, err := dialer.Dial(socketUrl, nil)
```

Your example however will not show that the messages are compressed as this is handled by the library.

You can verify it using something like Wireshark:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate ...
```

and on messages:

```
.1.. .... = Per-Message Compressed: True
```

You might also need to adjust the compression level to see the result you expect (max seems to be 9).